# open excel macro with c# in ASP.net(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to do that with the below command

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Tool.xlsx.xlsm");
```

it opens the Tool.xlsx.xlsm but give me an error "excel cannot open the file tool.xlsx.xlsm" because the file format of the extension is not supported

Comment: You're in ASP.NET. Why are you opening an Excel file with Process.Start? Are you trying to open it on the client or the server?

Comment: on client machine

Comment: Then your technique wont work. You can't launch programs on the clients computer from a server in normal circumstances. Think how big a security risk that would be. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: it is possible ... just need help to do that

Comment: You haven't answered my question. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: so why you wanna know that.. i thing is i am building is going to be used within my team so there are no security risks

Comment: I want to know that because it helps to have context to give you better advice. Assuming that all clients will "trust" the server, you can install some separate program on the client that listens for messages and launches applications. Or if your server has a user with rights on the client machine, you can look up a way to remotely launch a program.

Answer (score 0):

Please manually open with excel.
I think file format is xlsx not xlsm.